# splash screen in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen

I am new in flutter.I try to write splash screen.In flutter,in Android, there are two separate screens that you can control: a launch screen shown while your Android app initializes(white screen), and a splash screen that displays while the Flutter experience initializes(black screen).I wathed few tutorials,and did few apps with splesh screens.But it doesnt work correctly.My splash screen viewed after white and blak screens.I need to see my custom splash screen instead white and black screens.Is it possibly in flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the black and white splash screen color you need to edit the files in the native projects. 
Set the background color in the native projects to equal the flutter splash screen background color it will result in a really smooth transition between the native splash and the flutter one.